# Create a browse only queue in Redhat MRG/Apache QPID

Tags: java, jms, messaging, qpid

How can I enforce a queue to be browse only in Red Hat MRG/Apache QPID so that clients can only browse the queue. Even if some client tries to consume message off queue, he should not be able to do it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your use case? Why do you want a queue, with clients browsing but never consuming? Who consumes a message?  Would a database be better for your work flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is such an option to configure the broker, but your clients can connect to the queue in browse-only mode.

```
direct://amq.direct//myqueue?browse=true
```

---

**--EDIT--**

Another way to make clients use browse_only queues.

```
package foo.bar;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.qpid.client.AMQDestination;
import org.apache.qpid.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory;
import org.apache.qpid.jndi.ReadOnlyContext;

public class CustomPropertiesFileInitialContextFactory extends PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    @Override
    protected ReadOnlyContext createContext(Map data, Hashtable environment) {
        makeDestinationsReadOnly(data);
        return super.createContext(data, environment);
    }
    protected void makeDestinationsReadOnly(Map<String, AMQDestination> dests) {
        for(AMQDestination dest : dests.values()) {
            dest.setBrowseOnly(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to enforce this option. This way it is upon to discretion of client to choose browse only.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do what you want on the broker's side. You have to make your clients use browse_only option somehow. For example by means of custom _PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory_ like in my edited answer.

Comment: Agree with mijer, besides a browse only queue does not fit the jms model.

Comment: @mijer I need something that can be enforced on the broker. this way if a client wants to consumer some message, he can do this without anyone stopping him.

Comment: @ManojGumber, what is your usecase? With current implementation of MRG/qpid you cannot do it. At least you can be convinced of it by contacting MRG support. If you need `N` clients to consume the same message consider using one exchange that is binded to `N` queues. Then make each client consume messages only from its own queue. To restrict access of each client to not permitted queues there are [access control lists](https://cwiki.apache.org/qpid/acl.html)

Comment: @mijer My usecase is there is some data (which can be few million messages) that I want all clients to get whenever they come up. Having different queues for each, too much resources it will take. The same work a single queue can do but it has to be browse only enforced queue. Because I do not want that one client consumes the messages and others are deprived of it. I am talking with Redhat folks and will updates on what they say